# get coordinates of points that form circumference

Tags: java, awt, geometry-surface

I have an ellipse:

```
 Ellipse2D e2D  = new Ellipse2D.Float(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, x - startPoint.x, y - startPoint.y);
```

And what I need is to get coordinates of all points that form circumference.

```
ArrayList<Point> oneDraw = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = startX; i < borderX; i++)
        for (int j = startY; j < borderY; j++)
            if (e2D.contains(new Point(i, j))) 
                oneDraw.add(new Point(i, j));
```

By doing so, I put all coordinates that are inside my circle to the list, but I don't need this.

Thank you for the answer and spent time.

Comment: Is that from a library?

Comment: Sorry, what library? And what "that"?

Comment: I meant the classes you are using: `Point`, `Ellipse2D`. Are those from some library? I'm just not familiar with that.

Comment: Ah, they are 
java.awt.Point;
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

Comment: That's good to know. Can you add AWT to the tags?

Comment: @Yaroslav What's the problem with your code? You just want the points of the circunference, instead of all the inside points?

Comment: @MadEqua yes. I am not in good relations with geometry

Comment: The "border" in fact consists of *infinitely many* points. This seems like an XY-Problem (pun intended). You should describe what you actually want to *achieve*, on a higher level of abstraction. My guesses: 1. You either want to know the *pixels* that would be filled by a `g.draw(ellipse)` - this could be solved by painting into an image. Or 2.: You want to perform some sort of picking or collision detection. For this, you would simply compute the distance of a point to the border of the ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an ellipse that is a little larger than the target ellipse.
- Create an ellipse that is a little smaller than the target ellipse.
- Subtract the 2nd ellipse from the first.  This will form an elliptical ring.
- Do the current 'contains' code with the elliptical ring.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would add all pixels in the box which are inside the ellipse to the list, i.e. you'd get the *area* of the ellipse rather than its circumference. I'd say it would be better to look for the correct formula and solve it for discrete x/y pairs.

Or yet better apply one of the algorithms for drawing ellipses that can be found on the net, e.g. this one:  http://www.mathopenref.com/coordcirclealgorithm.html
Then get the pixels that have been drawn (if still needed).

*Edit:* if you have a look at the source code of `Ellipse2D` you can either get an an idea of how to implement your own algorithm or you could just use `getPathIterator()` with a uniform transform and then "rasterize" the path elements into your list.

Comment: "would add all pixels in the box which are not inside the ellipse to the list" -- do you mean "which are inside" rather than "which are not inside"?

Comment: @markw oh yes, you're right. I got confused by the OP wanting to get the "circumference" and then checking whether the ellipse contains the point. Seems as if my brain added a `!` in the condition.